# standalone software to generate heat map of movement from video

Tags: camera, heatmap

I need a software to analyse my CCTV video and show a heat map of movement like this picture:

[image]

I don’t want to use cloud base solutions like [this](https://www.accuware.com/products/indoor-tracking-video/) because I don’t have IP camera.

Also I’m programmer so if there is a programming solution let me know

Comment: Just checking if you have found something that works ? I have the same need. Cheers, JP

Comment: @JPNZ No, I didn't find anything. I'm going to build one with OpenCV library.

Comment: hey would it be possible to share the code?